# How to calculate value of score by subject name?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is what I've tried. But this code compute scores of all the list of documents. How to compute the scores by subject name or exam name?

```
documents.fold(
                  0,
                  (prev, next) =>
                      prev +
                      int.parse(
                        next['score'],
                      ),
                )


Stream getData() async* {
    final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final FirebaseUser user = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;

    QuerySnapshot qn = await db
        .collection('scores')
        .document(uid)
        .collection('exam_data')
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .getDocuments();

    yield qn.documents;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include a filter clause into the query to get the results relevant to you. Just substitute **field** and **value** with your actual parameters:

```
QuerySnapshot qn = await db
        .collection('scores')
        .document(uid)
        .collection('exam_data')
        .where(**field**, isEqualTo: **value**)
        .getDocuments();
```

I suggest you take a look at Firebase documentation pages about [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and [ordering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) since they offer a lot of valuable examples on this matter.